# solve Euler Lagrange equation when $f(u,z)=u^2+z^2$

Tags: euler-lagrange-equation

Write down the Euler-Lagrange equation for the following problem:
$$
\min { \int_0^1 f(u(x),u'(x))dx; \quad u(0)=0, u(1)=1 }
$$
Solve this Euler-Lagrange equation when $f(u,z) = z^2+u^2$

I have gotten the Euler-Lagrange into the form:
$df/du=d/dx(df/du')$
And differentiated $f(u,z) = z^2+u^2$,
But cannot proceed much further.

Comment: What do you mean you simplified $f(u,z) = z^2 + u^2$?

Comment: sorry it was differentiated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Euler-Lagrange equation for this is exactly as you pointed out
$$
\frac{d f}{d u} - \frac{d}{dx} \frac{d f}{d u'} = 0
$$
Now note that
$$
\frac{d f}{d u} = 2 u \\
\frac{d f}{d u'} = 2 u' \\
\frac{d}{dx} \frac{d f}{d u'} = 2 u''
$$
So we conclude that our system of equations is
$$
\left\{ \begin{array}{l} 2 u - 2u'' = 0 \\ u(0) = 0, u(1) = 1 \end{array} \right.
$$
And of course we can simplify this to solving (since a solution to the above system is a solution to the bottom and vice versa).
$$
\left\{ \begin{array}{l} u - u'' = 0 \\ u(0) = 0, u(1) = 1 \end{array} \right.
$$

**Note:** An important note I want to put here that you might be struggling with (I know I did) is that $\frac{d f}{d u}$ means to take the derivative of $f$ with respect to the first parameter - to me it was misleading that we were taking the derivative of a function with respect to another function. Likewise $\frac{d f}{d u'}$ means taking the derivative with respect to the second parameter.

---

Now as for solving this equation consider a solution of the form
$$
u(x) = ae^{b x}
$$
So that we get the constraint that
$$
a e^{b x} - ab^2 e^{b x} = 0 \implies 1 - b^2 = 0 \implies b^2 - 1 = 0
$$
Thus we must have
$$
b = \frac{\pm \sqrt{4}}{2} = \pm 1
$$
Since this is a homogenous equation we can add together these solutions and it will still be a solution so that we get a general equation of
$$
u_g(x) = a_1 e^{x} + a_2 e^{-x}
$$
Finally we incorporate boundary conditions
to get that
$$
u_g(0) = a_1 + a_2 = 0 \\
u_g(1) = a_1 e + a_2 e^{-1} = 1
$$
Which we can solve by seeing
$$
-a_1 = a_2 \implies a_1 e - a_1 e^{-1} = 1 \implies a_1 = \frac{1}{e - e^{-1}} = \frac{1}{2} \mathrm{csch}(1)
$$
So finally we get
$$
u_s = \frac{1}{2} \mathrm{csch}(1) e^{x} - \frac{1}{2} \mathrm{csch}(1) e^{-x}
$$

Comment: Thanks for the help, really appreciated.